# specific concerns for encrypting C++/Perl based apps so that database access credentials are never hacked

Tags: c++, perl, encryption

I am working on a cross platform app that will be created using C++-> mobile devices, and using Perl-> Desktop PCs (like Windows /Linux/Mac OS).

Now, since the app will be downloadable, I have concerns regarding the ability of hackers to obtain the source code of my app.

Specifically, the app will connect to my central database-- at the minimum, I want that hackers are not able to obtain my database connection details. Ideally, I would want no part of the code to be hacked.

Basically, the user can update some of his information using this app-- if hackers get hold of this data they can easily change any unfortunate user's data. One thing that I have thought of is that the user will have to initially authenticate with OAuth/OAuth2 ( using his email ID @yahoo/@hotmail/@gmail)-- and only after that the app will actually show the admin interface. But at any rate, at some point the app will connect to the central database-- which is why I dont want the database's access details to be compromised.

Many organisations make such apps, so they must be facing this type of problem themself? I would like to know how I can protect my app (ideally entire code), and atleast the db credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers are absolutely correct.  You want a server based service layer that provides the authentication/authorization code and interacts with the database.  However, it isn't always a perfect world and if you are stuck with the requirement that these applications must act as a database client you want to limit the exposure as much as possible.  Typically this is done by having the client use a specific account which has not been granted any access to the general database.  You then create specific stored procedures that can only do the operations and queries that are required of the application.  This prevents anyone finding the credentials in the code from doing anything in the database that isn't intended, but you still have the problem that anyone can impersonate someone else by reviewing the code.  There isn't a way to prevent that without a server side component.  This might be okay for a closed/trusted group of users, but I wouldn't release anything to the general public with this method.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is you do not expose your database. Ever.

Add a service layer (could be HTTP-based but doesn't have to be) on top that will deal with authentication and authorisation. Your app then logs in using the user's credentials and acts on their behalf. Your service layer exposes an API which your application talks to, but your service makes and controls *all* calls to the DB.

You already mention OAuth - that's a perfectly acceptable way of adding authentication to such an API.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

On the bright side you can put security on your server.  The connecting client provides credentials that they are a given user.  The server generates the SQL command after proving the request is allowed.  Backers can do anything your app can do, but your app becomes incapable of behaving badly to your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it, use OAuth2 and allow a trusted third party handle authentication.  Twitter, Facebook and GitHub are all relatively paranoid about security; and the other poster is correct: never expose direct db access as part of the app the user has access to; put it behind a service of its own.

Good luck! :)